# send email in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, email

I Want to send reset password email in laravel,with default laravel auth
first login in mailtrap.io and get username and password,then edit env file such as this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=mail.moallemmarket.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and edit mail.php file such as env,Now I receive `We have e-mailed your password reset link!` message But don't receive any email in my inbox,I changed ports to 25 ans 2525 But result is same.How I can Solved this problem?

Comment: did you restarted server after changing env file?

Comment: yes I do,But don't work

Comment: Check in laravel log file for more information about error located in `storage\logs`

Comment: @LeenaPatel I checked log,I don't Have any Error

Comment: can you check email in spam box?

Comment: @LeenaPatel Yes I do,spam box is empty

Comment: try to change `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` and restart server then check

Comment: @LeenaPatel How I can restart server?delete and re upload?

Comment: no run `php artisan serve` again

Comment: @LeenaPatel oof,Don't work sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem coding
The problem with the non-activation of the email was in the cpanel that was solved by sending the ticket

Answer (score -1):

With mailtrap, I use these vars in my .env file:

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null